# how to store form cleaned_data in a Django session

Tags: python, django

I am developing an ads web site using Django 3.0 and Python 3.8. I want to build multi step form wizard using django session. I have tried previously formtools.wizard but it failed to satisfy all of my requirements. Thus, I decided to write my own code to do that using session to pass form inputs from one class view to another. The first form go through with no error. However, I got the following error message before second form was rendered:

```
Object of type Country is not JSON serializable
```

The view classes are as follow:

```py
class PostWizardStepOne(View):

    form_class = CommonForm
    
    template_name = "towns/salehslist/ads_main_form.html"
    
    wizard_data = {}
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        initial = {
                'wizard_data':request.session.get('wizard_data', None),
            }
        form = self.form_class(initial=initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            for k, v in form.cleaned_data.items():
                self.wizard_data[k] = v
            request.session['wizard_data'] = self.wizard_data
            request.session.modified = True


            print(self.wizard_data)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('PostWizardSecondStep')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

class PostWizardStepTow(View):

    template_name = "towns/salehslist/forms/jobPostForm.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        print(request.session['wizard_data'])

        return render(request, self.template_name, {})
```

Here are the urls:

```
path('post/', PostWizardStepOne.as_view(), name = 'PostWizardFirstStep'),
path('post/', PostWizardStepTow.as_view(), name = 'PostWizardSecondStep'),
```

Here are the forms:

```py
class CommonForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Job

        fields = [

                    'country',
                    'province',
                    'city',
                    'category',
                    'sub_category',
            ]

class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # to remove colons from the labels:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super(JobForm , self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Job

        fields = [

                'employer',
                'title',
                'description',
                'Experience',
                'Education',
                'compensation',
                'employment_type',
            ]


class JobImagesForm(forms.Form):


    # to remove colons from the labels:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super(JobImagesForm , self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['image'].widget.attrs.update({ 'type':'file', 
            'accept':'image/*',})

    class Meta:
    
        model = JobImages

        fields = [
            'image',
        ]
```

Those are the models;

```py
    # country model
    class Country(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
        currency = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return "%s" % (self.name)
    
        class Meta:
                verbose_name_plural = "countries"
    
    
        class Job(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        posted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        employer = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        province = models.ForeignKey(Province, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
        title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        description = RichTextField(max_length=65536)
        Experience = RichTextField(max_length=65536)
        Education = RichTextField(max_length=65536)
    
        compensation = models.CharField(max_length=65536, blank=True)
        employment_type = models.ForeignKey(Employment_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now =False, auto_now_add=True)
        date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    
        
    
        def __str__(self):
            return "%s %s %s" % (self.id, self.employer, self.title,)
    
    
        def username(self):
            return self.posted_by.first_name
    
        def categoryName(self):
            return self.category.name
    
        def subCategoryName(self):
            return self.sub_category.name
    
        def country_name(self):
            return self.country.name
    
        def province_name(self):
            return self.province.name
    
        def city_name(self):
            return self.city.name
    
        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "jobs"
```

Here are the settings for backend:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'django.contrib.sessions', ]

MIDDLEWARE = ['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',]
```

I am trying to save the 5 input of the first form into 1 variable called `wizard_data`. and add to it the other inputs value from second and third forms, respectively, and finally save all of them into the data base and clear the session.

Comment: A common pattern for workflows like this is to save the data in the DB. Is there a reason The DB in combination w/ a status will not work?

Comment: This is a multi steps form. The second step will be different based on category selection. There will be condition for redirect. It is not necessary to redirect to PostWizardStepTow it will redirect to different view class for different category.

Comment: Can you post the models? What is the `Country` object that it cannot be serialized ?

Comment: Sure. Models are available.

Comment: What is the session backend? I am able to store complex objects querysets, etc in testing code. I am using a database backed session.

Comment: which aspect of form wizard did not satisfy your needs?

Comment: HI ha-neul. uploading mutiple images in the 3rd step. I do not want to use formset. because using this must set how many form inputs. I do not want to show many inputs for user. it looks ugly. I want users to upload as many images as they want with one click for 1 input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around the following solution worked for me:

```py
class PostWizardStepOne(View):

    form_class = CommonForm
    
    template_name = "towns/salehslist/ads_main_form.html"

    wizard_data = {}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        initial = {
                'wizard_data':request.session.get('wizard_data', None),
            }
        form = self.form_class(initial=initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    
        if form.is_valid():
            # <process form cleaned data>
            for k, v in form.cleaned_data.items():
                self.wizard_data[k] = v
            
            form_data = json.dumps(self.wizard_data, default=lambda x: x.__dict__)
            request.session['wizard_data'] = form_data
            
            request.session.modified = True


            print(self.wizard_data)
            return redirect('PostWizardSecondStep')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```